# Get the right name of the Container related to an Azure Web App

Tags: azure, web-applications, containers

Is it possible to exec a command in a windows container related to a webapp based on a container? I'm not able to find the right name to use on the cli command `az app exec`. In fact `az container list` returns me an empty list. However the container exits cause the web app is running. Where can I find the right name to use with az app exec command? I also checked with the name of only one slot in the webapp without success.

The error `az app exec` returns is:

The Resource 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/theNameIPRovide' under resource group 'thegroupNameIProvide' was not found.

Comment: `az app` command doesnt exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no Azure CLI command for Web app for Container to exec the command inside the container. But you can use other ways, for example, the API.

There is no CLI command like `az app exec`. And `az container` is for ACI, not for the Web App. You can get all CLI command for Web App in [`az webapp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest).

Or you can deploy your application in Azure Container Instance, it also can run windows container for you. So that you can use the CLI command [`az container exec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-exec) to execute the command inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-exec, Couldnt comment, so had to post it in an answer